# Android: Placing selector over View

Tags: android

OK so I have a `GridView` of selectable items. Now, I am fully aware of how to create custom selectors for items. The problem is that whenever an item in the `GridView` is pressed, the selector is completely blocked by the grid item.

Is there any way to make it so that the selector appears over my grid item view? An example of this can be seen in the ''Play Music'' app. When you select an album in the grid a semi-transparent orange overlay appears on the item to indicate that it is being pressed.

Any ideas on how I would approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so the solution to this is stupidly simple. You just use the attribute `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` in the XML element corresponding to your `AdapterView`.